# How do check if a time is greater than a particular one?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, if-statement, sql-server-2014-express

I am building a windows form application and for my database I want to create a procedure to insert values. For this procedure I want to check if the time is later than 8:45 then you are considered late.
Here is what I was trying so far

```
 Create Procedure "Insert Attendance"
(
    @att_id int,
    @emp_id     integer,
    @work_date      date,   
    @expected_time      time(7)         
    @time_in        time(7),            
    @time_out       time(7),            
    @time_elapse time(7),           
    @time_status varchar(20)            
)
As
Begin
    If ((time_in=@time_in)>16:45)
 then set time_status = 'Late'
        Begin
            Insert Into attendance
            Values
            (@att_id,@emp_id,@work_date,@expected_time,@time_in,@time_out,@time_elapse,@time_status)
        End
    Else
        Begin
            Select 'Error'
        End
End
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string constants to define the time to compare to:

```
...
IF @time_in > '08:45'
BEGIN
  SET time_status = 'Late';
...
```

Also note, that in SQL Server there is no `THEN` for `IF`.